# Determining the shape of result array after slicing in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have difficult time understanding how the shape of resultant array be determined after slicing in numpy. For example I am using the following simple code:

```
import numpy as np


array=np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)

slice1 = array[:,1:2,1]
slice2= array[:,1,1]

print "Content in slice1 is  ", slice1
print "Shape of slice1 is ", slice1.shape
print "Content in slice2 is ",slice2
print "Shape of Slice2 is", slice2.shape
```

Output of this is:

```
Content in slice1 is 
 [[ 4]
  [13]
  [22]]
Shape of slice1 is  (3, 1)
Content in slice2 is  [ 4 13 22]
Shape of Slice2 is (3,)
```

In both of these cases, content is same(as it should be). But they differ in shapes. So, how does the resultant shape is determined by numpy?

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: Basically: slicing does not reduce the number of dimensions, but indexing with an integer reduces the number of dimensions by 1 each time.

Comment: There is a `shape` attribute.  Look at `x.__array_interface__` to see it and other attributes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It basically boils down to this -

```
In [118]: a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

In [119]: a[1:2]
Out[119]: array([2])

In [120]: a[1]
Out[120]: 2
```

When you do `a[1:2]`, you are asking for an array with 1 element.

When you do `a[1]` you are asking for the element at that index.

---

Similar thing happens in your case.

When you do - `array[:,1:2,1]` - it means all possible indexes from first dimension , a sub-list of indexes from second dimension (though the sub-list only contains one element) , and 1st index from third dimension. So you get back a array of arrays -

```
 [[ 4]
  [13]
  [22]]
```

When you do - `array[:,1,1]` - it means all possible indexes from first dimension, 1st index from second dimension, and 1st index from third dimension. So you get back an array -

```
[4 13 22]
```