# The shape of a sliced array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have problems about the array calculation after it is being sliced. THe problem is cased by the uncertainty of the shape of the sliced array.

For example, I have a 2D array `data` with shape of `(118,3)`, however, when I only use the first column of data as following, I can only determine the shape as `(118,)`.  The `#column` cannot be determined unless I use `reshape`. I do not understand why.

```
print shape(data), shape(data[:, 0])
```

The result is : `(118, 3) (118,)`.

I have found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647493/determining-the-shape-of-result-array-after-slicing-in-numpy) asked on stackoverflow. But it did not answer my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving a concrete index for a dimension, reduces this dimension in the result. If you want to keep this dimension, you have to provide a one-element slice:

```
print data[:, 0:1].shape
```

results in `(118, 1)`.